# Como llamar un registro tipo clob desde php

Tags: php, oracle-11g

Estoy llamando a un registro y lo estoy almacenando en un array asociativo, y al momento de ejecutar la pagina NO ME APARECE EL RESULTADO, es más, YA NO CARGA EL RESTO DE LA PAGINA, es como si hubiera puesto un die(). AQUÍ MI CODIGO:

**BASE DE DATOS**

```
CREATE TABLE TBLPRUEBA
(
ID_ACORDEON NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
DESCRIP_ACORDEON CLOB
);
```

**EL REGISTRO QUE TIENE LA TABLA**

```
    DECLARE 
    str_html CLOB := '
                                        <div class="contenedor-panel">
                                            <div class="panel-ficha">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[0]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto">
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[1]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_gestion_educativa_1.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[2]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_gestion_educativa_2.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[3]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_gestion_educativa_3.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[4]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_gestion_educativa_4.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[5]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_gestion_educativa_5.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-ficha">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[6]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto">
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[7]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_promocion_educativa_zonales_1.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[8]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_promocion_educativa_zonales_2.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[9]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_promocion_educativa_zonales_3.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[10]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_promocion_educativa_zonales_4.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[11]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_promocion_educativa_zonales_5.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-ficha">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[12]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto">
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[13]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_coordinacion_educativa_zonales_1.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[14]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_coordinacion_educativa_zonales_2.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[15]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_coordinacion_educativa_zonales_3.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[16]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_coordinacion_educativa_zonales_4.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[17]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_coordinacion_educativa_zonales_5.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-ficha">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[18]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto">
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[19]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_coordinacion_academica_est_1.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[20]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_coordinacion_academica_est_2.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[21]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_coordinacion_academica_est_3.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[22]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_coordinacion_academica_est_4.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[23]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_coordinacion_academica_est_5.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-ficha">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[24]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto">
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[25]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_del_desempeno_docente_1.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[26]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_del_desempeno_docente_2.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                    <?php echo $cabecera[27]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                    <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_del_desempeno_docente_3.php"; ?>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>';  
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO TBLPRUEBA VALUES(1, str_html);
    COMMIT;
END;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CODIGO PHP PARA OBTENER EL REGISTRO**

```
<?php
class Contenido
{

    private $arreglo = array();

    public function listarAcordeon()
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM TBLPRUEBA';
        $stid = oci_parse(conex::con(), $sql);
        oci_execute($stid);
        while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) {
            $this->arreglo[] = $row;
        }
        return $this->arreglo;
        oci_free_statement($stid);
        oci_close(conex::con());
    }
}
?>

<?php
include '../class/class_acordeon.php';
$prueba = new Contenido();
$tabla = $prueba->listarAcordeon();
?>

<?php
....CODIGO
<?=$tabla[0]["DESCRIP_ACORDEON"]?>//ACÁ DEBERIA APARECERME TODO EL SCRIPT QUE ESTABA DENTRO DEL CLOB, PERO NO ME CARGA.
....CODIGO
?>
```

Comment: Dentro de ese registro de tipo CLOB he puesto varias etiquetas HTML como puse en mi post, y no sabia que el BLOB se llamaba de otra forma.

Comment: ¿Eres consciente de que la columna `DESCRIP_ACORDEON` es del tipo `CLOB`? ¿Está justificado usar ese tipo de dato para esa columna?  ¿`DESCRIP_ACORDEON` es algo así como texto para un libro o una imagen cifrada?... Para leer/mostrar datos `CLOB` quizá te conviene [leer esto](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.OCI-Lob.php), sobre todo el [método `read`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/oci-lob.read.php) y también el  [método `load`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/oci-lob.load.php). El problema es que los objetos grandes pueden exceder la memoria, `read` te ayudará a leerlos sin problemas.

Comment: ok, gracias, por como veo primero tendre que usar read y luego load

Comment: No sé si mejor te conviene un tipo de dato `TEXT` ya que hablas de contenido HTML. `CLOB` y `BLOB` son casi siempre para archivos, imágenes pesadas, o contenido amplio, algo así como un libro completo.

Comment: Usar TEXT, ok vere que me sale de todo el cambio que haga y te cuento si tuve exito o no :)

Comment: Haz copia de tu base de datos antes de cambiar tipos de datos. Y revisa qué tipo de dato te conviene más según tus necesidades. Yo no es que sea experto en Oracle. Revisa los tipos de dato y sus capacidades.

Comment: Justo te iba preguntar que NO existe el tipo de dato TEXT, pero no importa, con lo que me mostraste de los metodos read y load es suficiente.

Comment: Lo que sí leí es que un `CLOB` te admite hasta `2GB` de tamaño. Ese tipo de dato entonces es alta gama (me parece) como para guardar en él un HTML. ¿Crees que tu HTML llegará más o menos a 2GB? Debe haber tipos de dato con capacidad intermedia. Todo depende siempre de lo que vayas a almacenar ahí.

Comment: Tambien me planteé eso, pero lo que pase es que toda mis etiquetas HTML sobrepasan los 8000 caracteres, el varchar2 no soporta esa cantidad y me botaba error, asi que pregunte y me recomendaron colocarlo en CLOB

Comment: Si te recomendaron eso quizá sea así, como te dije, conozco muy poco sobre Oracle, pero supongo que está optimizado para guardar en `CLOB` contenido relativamente pequeño para su capacidad. Quizá alguien con más experiencia en Oracle pudiera intervernir al respecto o puedes preguntar específicamente sobre eso. De todos modos, si quieres leer el CLOB, revisa la clase `Lob`, creo que tendrás que hacer uso de ella.

Comment: Amigo @A.Cedano, tuve exito ;), solo tenia que poner ->load() o ->read(cantidad_de_caracteres). Pero ahora el unico problema es que el codigo PHP que puse en la BD no se ejecuta en cuando esta en la página. Sé que cualquier codigo servidor NUNCA sera mostrado en la página, pero que NO se ejecute eso si es muy raro.

Comment: ¿Cómo, pusiste código PHP en la BD?  ¿?

Comment: Esta en mi post, esta combinado junto con el codigo HTML

Comment: Es que eso sería muy peligroso. ¿Realmente estás poniendo código PHP en un registro de la BD para que luego se ejecute ese código?¿Por qué ese proceder? En cualquier caso, una vez seas consciente del alto riesgo que eso supone, para que se ejecute tendrías que crear un archivo PHP o incluir ese contenido en un archivo PHP y ejecutarlo. Me parece muy raro querer hacer eso

Comment: WOW, tendre más cuidado :(, pero me estas diciendo que cree un archivo php y adentro coloque otro archivo php que tendre todo el codigo?

Comment: Agregue el codigo porque hay datos que estoy jalando de ahí, como por ejemplo el nombre de los titulos y más codigo HTML combinado con PHP. En resumen, solo lo puse por orden y por obtener otros datos de la BD

Comment: No, no te digo que hagas eso, te digo que para que funcione tendría que ser así. El código PHP para ejecutarse, tiene que estar en un archivo PHP. Pero hacer eso sería una locura. Si cualquier usuario manipula ese registro puede meter lo que sea y eso se ejecutaría en el servidor. Me pregunto por qué no creas tus programas en el servidor y luego les pides los datos que haga falta a la base de datos. Es que todavía no entiendo qué sentido tiene guardar una página entera en una base de datos ¿? Ya lo del HTML entero me parecía raro, pero cuando dijiste que tenía código PHP dentro, uffff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma.

```
select ID_ACORDEON, DBMS_LOB.substr(DESCRIP_ACORDEON, 4000) DESCRIP_ACORDEON from TBLPRUEBA;
```

ahora solo seria hacer un:

```
echo $tabla[0]["DESCRIP_ACORDEON"];
```

> **nota:** el codigo php saldra comentado como si fuera html ya que el interprete lo tomara como texto plano!

Comment: Hola @Bryro, ¿cómo podria hacer para que se ejecute el codigo PHP? :)

Comment: si se podria pero no seria lo correcto, traerira grandes problemas de seguridad ya que cualquier codigo malisioso podria ser ejecutado! restructurar tu codigo de una manera correcta! ya que estas guardando codigo php dentro de tu base de datos! aparte de que es un codigo repetitivo por lo que vi!

Comment: no te preocupes, lo que hago es de prueba

Comment: El amigo @A. Cedano ya me advirtio que es demasiado peligroso, pero solo quiero ver si me puede ejecutarse un metodo.

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal te contestare en tu pregunta! https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/250684/como-colocar-fragmentos-de-codigo-php-en-oracle