# ejecutar string como codigo php

Tags: php, oracle-11g

Acabo de añadir un fragmentos de codigo PHP más HTML y todo eso lo añadi a mi tabla TBLPRUEBA, el problema es que al momento de llamar el codigo NO SE EJECUTA EL CODIGO PHP, pero si llega a colocarse el codigo HTML.

**Tabla en Oracle**

```
CREATE TABLE TBLPRUEBA
(
ID_ACORDEON NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
DESCRIP_ACORDEON CLOB
);
```

**Codigo PHP + HTML**

```
<div class="contenedor-panel">
                                        <div class="panel-ficha">
                                            <?php echo $cabecera[0]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-aspecto">
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[1]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_gestion_educativa_1.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[2]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_gestion_educativa_2.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[3]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_gestion_educativa_3.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[4]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_gestion_educativa_4.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[5]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_gestion_educativa_5.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-ficha">
                                            <?php echo $cabecera[6]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-aspecto">
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[7]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_promocion_educativa_zonales_1.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[8]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_promocion_educativa_zonales_2.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[9]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_promocion_educativa_zonales_3.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[10]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_promocion_educativa_zonales_4.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[11]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_promocion_educativa_zonales_5.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-ficha">
                                            <?php echo $cabecera[12]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-aspecto">
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[13]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_coordinacion_educativa_zonales_1.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[14]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_coordinacion_educativa_zonales_2.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[15]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_coordinacion_educativa_zonales_3.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[16]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_coordinacion_educativa_zonales_4.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[17]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_de_coordinacion_educativa_zonales_5.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-ficha">
                                            <?php echo $cabecera[18]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-aspecto">
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[19]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_coordinacion_academica_est_1.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[20]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_coordinacion_academica_est_2.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[21]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_coordinacion_academica_est_3.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[22]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_coordinacion_academica_est_4.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[23]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_valoracion_de_coordinacion_academica_est_5.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-ficha">
                                            <?php echo $cabecera[24]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-aspecto">
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[25]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_del_desempeno_docente_1.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[26]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_del_desempeno_docente_2.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion">
                                                <?php echo $cabecera[27]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]; ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-aspecto-descripcion-indicadores">
                                                <?php require_once "include/ficha_de_evaluacion_del_desempeno_docente_3.php"; ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

**EJECUTAR SCRIPT**

```
<?php echo $tabla[0]["DESCRIP_ACORDEON"] -> load()?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes hacero asi:

> **nota:**
>   todas las variable deberian existir antes de esta ejecucion!
>   debo agregar es que es un codigo sumamente peligroso.
>   que no deberia ser llevado a produccion ni puesto en practica.
>   lo agrego como metodo de ilustrativo de estudio y posible solucion a una interrogante.
>   no es un solucion viable. `recomiendo re-evaluar la logica` y sacar todo codigo `php` del la base de datos!

```
// almacenamos el primer resultado de la base de datos
$resultado = $res["DESCRIP_ACORDEON"][0];

// creamos un array dividiendo por el codigo php
$html = preg_split("'<\?php(.*?)\?>'", $resultado);
// seleccionamos todo el codigo php
preg_match_all("'<\?php(.*?)\?>'", $resultado, $php);
// seleccionamos el elemento 1 que contiene el resultado del preg_match_all!
$php = $php[1];

// hacemos un loop para cada elemento html
for ($i=0; $i < $html ; $i++) {
    // imprimimos el html
    echo $html[$i];
    // validamos que exista codigo php para esa posicion
    if (isset($php[$i])) {
        // aplicamos eval que evalua y ejecuta nuestro codigo!
       eval($php[$i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: una consulta amigo @Bryro, la variable $php que vendria a ser?

Comment: Cuando llamo a la BD utilizo esto: echo $tabla[0]["DESCRIP_ACORDEON"]->load(); Además reemplace el "echo" por "print" porque me botaba error de sintaxis y por último, cuando ejecute todo el script, no se cargo nada. :(

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal 1. esta totalmente comentado es el resultado de el `pre_match_all` 2. lo hice asi solo para tener el primer elemento es `ilustrativo` y `recalco` esta todo comentado. nota: sera la ultima ayuda e notado que es tu cuarta pregunta a este tema y creo que estoy haciendote la tarea! `stackoverflow` es una comunidad para despejar dudas solamente  o recibir asesoria en cuanto a 1 error y lo estas utilizandolo de forma inadecuada!

Comment: Para nada bro, soy nuevo en PHP y no soy de esas personas que van a foros a pedir que los ayuden en sus tareas.

Comment: A yaaaa, ok ok es algo ilustrativo, vere como lo corrijo.

Comment: Ya me funciono el código, gracias por la ayuda y perdón por no marcar tu respuesta como la definitiva :)

Answer (score 1):

Para que el texto leido desde la base de datos pueda ser ejecutado como código PHP necesitas la función [eval()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.eval.php)

```
eval("texto a ejecutar");
```

Sin embargo, esto puede resultar muy peligroso porque puede ejecutar cualquier tipo de código, no es lo más recomendable.

Comment: Hola @ReneLimon, estoy colocando eval() y nada. ¿CÓmo aplicas el eval en la BD?

Comment: <div class="contenedor-panel">
                                            <div class="panel-ficha">
                                                <?php eval(echo $cabecera[0]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"];)?>
                                            </div>

Comment: Así lo estoy colocando y nada

Comment: eval lo utilizas desde el script en donde llamas a la bd, si la función la metes dentro del campo de la bd seguirá siendo texto plano

Comment: entonces tendria que ir aquí?: <?php echo eval($tabla[0]["DESCRIP_ACORDEON"] -> load())?>

Comment: sí, pero es probable que te indique algún error de ejecución por que tambien tienes código html, lo ideal seria que separaras el html y solo aplicar el **eval** en el código de php

Answer (score 0):

Esto deberia estar en un comentario, porque no es respuesta, pero aun no tengo el nivel para hacer comentarios.

Lo que quiero mencionar es que hasta el punto que se puede ver en el codigo aun no has hecho la consulta a la base de datos, y asumo que las variables que estas queriendo mostrar no tienen valores, por tanto no te mostraran nada.

De igual manera es una buena practica limpiar las variables antes de una consulta, te sirven también para ver si esta o no realizando la consulta.

Comment: Hola @user3495626, si le he hecho una consulta a la BD, solo que no lo puse porque en mi post puse que si se ejecuta y metrae los resultados, PERO NO ME EJECUTA EL CODIGO PHP que esta combinado con el HTML

Comment: a veces es conveniente ir revisando paso a paso el valor de las variables, puedes imprimirlo dentro de la consulta, al salir de la consulta y cuando lo vuelves a usar, es un poco hacer una prueba de escritorio a tu codigo. 
No deja de llamarme la atencion que uses 

$cabecera[0]["NOMBRE_CABECERA"]

Por lo que veo en el codigo seria inecesario tener ["NOMBRE_CABECERA"] dandole otra dimension mas a tu array, ya que al final cada columna tiene un valor diferente.